# Linked list with Template

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I need to build a linked list with a template, but I have no idea why is not working, I've built linked lists before, but never with templates. Right now my problem is that, if I create the list everything is ok, but when I try to insert something to it, I get the following errors:

```
Error   C2664   'Nodo<D>::Nodo(Nodo<D> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const int' to 'const Nodo<D> &'    Datos2  d:\google drive\visual studio 2015\projects\datos2\datos2\listaSimple.h 69


Error   C2664   'Nodo<D>::Nodo(Nodo<D> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const int' to 'const Nodo<D> &'    Datos2  d:\google drive\visual studio 2015\projects\datos2\datos2\listaSimple.h 73
```

with my following code:

```
    //linkedList.h
#pragma once
#ifndef _LISTASIMPLE_H
#define _LISTASIMPLE_H

template<class D> 
struct Nodo
{
    int carga;
    int binario;

    D caracter;

    Nodo<D> *Siguiente;//means next
};



template<class D>
class listaSimple
{

public:
    listaSimple();
    ~listaSimple();

    void InsertarInicio(const D&);
    bool ListaVacia();
    void Mostrar();




private:
    Nodo<D> *primero;
    Nodo<D> *ultimo;

};

template<class D> 
listaSimple<D>::listaSimple()
{
    primero = NULL;
}

template<class D>
listaSimple<D>::~listaSimple()
{
    Nodo<D> *aux;
    while (primero != NULL)
    {
        aux = primero;
        primero = primero->Siguiente;
        delete aux;
    }
}

template<class D>
void listaSimple<D>::InsertarInicio(const D& dato)
{
    if (ListaVacia())
    {
        primero = new Nodo<D>(dato);
    }
    else
    {
        Nodo<D> *nodoNuevo = new Nodo<D>(dato);
        nodoNuevo->Siguiente = primero;
        primero = nodoNuevo;
    }
}

template<class D>
bool listaSimple<D>::ListaVacia()
{
    if (primero == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

template<class D>
inline
void listaSimple<D>::Mostrar()
{
    Nodo<D> *aux = primero;
    while (aux != NULL)
    {
        cout << aux->caracter << "->";
        aux = aux->Siguiente;
    }
}
```

and

```
//Source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "linkedList.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {
    listaSimple<int> Nueva;
    Nueva.InsertarInicio(5);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (EmptyList)` is that the actual code? Because you seem to want to call the function, in which case you are missing parentheses, e.g.: `if (EmptyList())`

Comment: @UnholySheep yep, sorry, translation error. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What is `Siguiente`? Also `class D` is not defined. `listaSimple<int> NewList` is all wrong, you probably mean `linkedList<D> NewList` where my `D` is some class which is not shown.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I edited the errors, siguiente means next in spanish, and lista Simple means "simple list". Is there a difference in using "template<class D>" vs using "template<typename D>?" as far as I've read, is exactly the same

Comment: "I edited the errors". No you did not. There is still "Nodo". The errors you have posted do not match actual errors present in the code. Please post **the exact code you have compiled**, rather than some edited version thereof, and post **the exact errors you are getting**. Use **copy and paste mechanism** without any editing whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m. done, any questions on what a variable does, please ask, I figured It would be best to translate it since the userbase here is english speaking

Comment: You are trying to create a node like this: `new Nodo<D>(dato);` where `dato` is a `const D&`. What exactly gives you right to do so? The class doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `D` or a `const D&` or any variant thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the corrected version of `Node` and `linkedList`. Note that `Node` and `linkedList` do not contain any information about the actual data. In fact you can declare the data (`struct MyData`) at the end.

For printing I added a function to:

```
node->data.print();
```

This way `Node` and `linkedList` are not directly responsible for printing the data, and they don't need to know anything about the data. They can ask `DataType` to print the data. `DataType` must contain a `print` function to print its own content.

```
template<typename DataType>
struct Node
{
    DataType data;
    Node<DataType> *Next;
    Node()
    {
        Next = nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename DataType>
class linkedList
{
public:
    linkedList()
    {
        first = NULL;
    }

    ~linkedList()
    {
        Node<DataType> *aux;
        while (first != NULL)
        {
            aux = first;
            first = first->Next;
            delete aux;
        }
    }

    void InsertBegining(const DataType& data)
    {
        Node<DataType> *newNode = new Node<DataType>;
        newNode->data = data;
        if (first)
        {
            newNode->Next = first;
            first = newNode;
        }

        first = newNode; //<== you forgot this
    }

    void Print()
    {
        Node<DataType> *walk = first;
        while (walk)
        {
            walk->data.print();
            walk = walk->Next;
        }
    }

private:
    Node<DataType> *first;
};
```

Now you can declare `MyData` and use it. Make sure `MyData` includes a `print` function. Also `MyData` has to be POD (plain old data, it can't contain pointers) because of the way data is being assigned.

```
int main() 
{
    struct MyData
    {
        int charge;
        int binario;
        char ch;
        void print()
        {
            cout << charge << ", " << binario << ", " << ch << "\n";
        }
    };

    linkedList<MyData> list;
    MyData data;

    data.binario = 1;
    data.ch = 'A';
    data.charge = 10;
    list.InsertBegining(data);

    data.binario = 2;
    data.ch = 'B';
    data.charge = 20;
    list.InsertBegining(data);

    list.Print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Another method:

You can add `<<` operator overload for `MyData`

```
struct MyData
{
    int charge;
    int binario;
    char ch;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, MyData &x)
    {
        out << x.ch << ", " << x.binario << ", " << x.charge;
        return out;
    }
};
```

So `MyData` knows how to print itself. Example:

```
MyData data;
data.ch = 'A';
data.binario = 1;
data.charge = 10;
cout << data << "\n";
```

This should print `"A, 1, 10"`.

Then you can change the `linkList::Print()` to

```
...
void Print()
{
    Node<DataType> *walk = first;
    while (walk)
    {
        std::cout << walk->data << "\n";
        walk = walk->Next;
    }
}
```

Now `linkedList` is independent of `MyData` as long as `MyData` has `<<` operator overload (and its data is POD). You can also use this linked list for fundamental types. Example:

```
linkedList<int> test;
test.InsertBegining(1);
test.InsertBegining(2);
test.Print();
```

Comment: that's great! But I still have some questions, do I have to declare a <myData> struct every time I want to use the template?

Comment: That's a very basic question, think about how it works and try declaration in different places to see what works. You can declare `MyData` in global scope and use it everywhere.

Comment: I thought of that, but since templates are giving me such a headache I though I should ask first. In any case, thanks for helping me out, I think I'm getting the hang of it now

Comment: By the way you can also overload `<<` operator for `MyData`, see updated answer.